# Вложенный qsqlquerymodel (Qt Quick)

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, qml

Есть две таблицы(SQLite), например *Tracks*(название GPS треков) и *Point*(Координаты каждой точки)
*Track* имеет такое строение:
**id** - ключ
**name** - название

Вторая таблица *Point*:
**track_id** - не ключ. Указывает к какому треку принадлежит точка
**lat** - широта
**lon** - долгота

Первая модель (TrackModel) получает названия треков.  Ее .h файл который выглядит так

```
class TracksModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum Roles {
        IdRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,      // id
        NameRole                        // имя                        // ник
    };

    explicit TracksModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

signals:

public slots:
    void updateModel();
    int getId(int row);
};
```

Вторая модель получает точки, по id трека. Класс отличается только SQL запросом(к другой таблице).

Задача заключается в том, чтобы отображать на Map только определенные треки. И для логичности хранения я хочу реализовать вложенную структуру моделей. Как это сделать? Как создать qsqlquerymodel в qsqlquerymodel и его можно было использоваться в qml

Comment: Вложенные модели в Qt не поддерживаются из коробки. Но зачем Вам это, если для фильтрации и конкатенации колонок таблиц можно использовать `join` из `sql`?

Comment: @alexis031182 Для каждого трека свое отображение. Чекбоксами я получаю необходимые мне id треков и начинаю выводить их из другой таблицы. Если я попытаюсь сделать как вы сказали, то, например, polyline соединить все треки одной линией.